# The repeat markers in positioning (Android API-2)?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I have a code which determine my position on google map by a marker when the position is changed the previous marker remains and it repeats in the new position. I want to have only marker when updating the position.
Here is my code :

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private GoogleMap map;
    Marker marker;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
        networkLocation();

    }

    private void animateToLocation(double latitude, double longtitude) {
        LatLng latlang = new LatLng(latitude, longtitude);
        CameraPosition position1 = CameraPosition.builder().target(latlang)
                .zoom(15).build();
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(position1));
        marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title("TEST").position(
                latlang));
        map.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
        map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latlang, 100));

    }

    public void networkLocation() {
        G.locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new LocationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                            Bundle extras) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                        animateToLocation(location.getLatitude(),
                                location.getLongitude());
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert `map.clear();` befor  :

```
marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title("TEST").position(latlang));
```

And your result is :

```
map.clear();
marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title("TEST").position(latlang));
```

And you can use your code...Correctly.
Good look

Comment: This just clears all the items on the map and adds a new marker right? I wouldn't want to do that if there were other useful markers on the map. But guess this works in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are using

```
marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title("TEST").position(
            latlang));
```

which actually adds a new marker on the map each time `animateToLocation(lat, lng)` is called. What you need to actually do is call

```
marker.setPostion(latLng);
```

there instead and initialize the marker somewhere at the beginning of your activity.

Comment: I use marker.setPostion(latLng); but give me crash .

Comment: Please give me a link for use marker.setPostion(latLng); and how i add  this to map... . I can't add marker.setPostion(latLng); to my map.addMarker(...);

Comment: Don't add marker.setPosition(latLng) inside map.addMarker(...) instead, replace it. Here is a SO question which explains this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15905359/how-to-change-the-position-of-a-marker-on-a-android-map-v2